# Nested for loops in C

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, nested, sequence

I'm try to complete a task set by a lecturer and I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 100

int main(void)
{
  int i, a, cnt = 1;

for (a = 1; a < 6; a++){
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++, cnt++) {
    if (a%2 > 0){
      a = 3*a + 1;
    }
    else{
      a = (a/2);
    }
    printf("%3d\n", a);
    if (a == 1){
      printf("Count: %d\n", cnt);
      return 0;
    }
  }
}
return 0;
}
```

The point of this code is to run a hailstone sequence on each integer, a. For now I have it to start at a = 1, then adding 1 to a, and running the sequence again up until a = 5.

This code runs it for the initial value of a but doesn't then add one to a to run it again. I really can't see why it won't do the outer loop again, please help!

A hailstone sequence is where it takes the integer before it in the sequence, if this integer is odd it computes 3*a +1, and if the integer is even it computes a/2. I've told the sequence to stop once a = 1.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: do not understand - what do you mean by `hailstone sequence`

Comment: Sorry, I thought it might have been a well known thing. It's just a sequence that, if a number is odd it computes the next number to be 3*n + 1. If the number is even it computes  n/2. So if the initial number was 5, the sequence would be:

5 16 8 4 2 1

Comment: maybe it is but i think you should include that info in the question ( ive not heard of it called by this name )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of return 0; in second loop add break; to move out of the inner loop and continue with outer loop.

If you don't want to add break this is another way and there are minor changes in your code which I have highlighted below.

```
1. You will have to reinititlize cnt for every new value of a.
2. You will have to take a new variable instead of a for calculations
3. For moving out of loop you can increase value of i.

#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int i, a, cnt=1, b;

for(a=1; a<6; a++){
    cnt = 1;
    b = a;
    for(i=0; i<100; i++, cnt++){
        if(b%2 > 0){
            b = 3*b + 1;
        }
        else{
            b = b/2;
        }

        printf("%d ", b);
        if(b==1){
            printf("\nCount %d\n", cnt);
            i = 100;
        }
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: My lecturer has told us that we're not allowed to use break in for loops, he only wants them in switch statements. But if I do add in break instead of return 0, it continually returns:

Count: 3
1

Comment: That's great! Thank you so much, it works :). Just before you posted it I was thinking it would be getting confused with a as I'd used it in multiple places. Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

I'm only a student too, but try removing the first "return 0;", I think that's what is ending the code early.

Comment: If I remove the return 0 inside the inner loop it continually computes cnt++, the output being tens of thousands of Count:. :/

Comment: try replacing it by break

Comment: See my comment to Varun.

Answer (score 0):

return will end the function. I think what you are looking for is break

Comment: See my comment to Varun.